# TFS 2018: View instance-level information

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

We are using TFS, in this case, for our project management (Work section).

I have a server (TFS) with a collection (Default Collection) and a project (My Project)

I have created a TFS group under that project (Consultants)

Consultant permissions are then set as appropriate for their role- including "*view project-level information*".

When going to the Work part of "My Project" it says the user needs "*view instance-level information*" which isn't an option at the project level, only for a group made at the Collection Level.

It seems impractical to create "Consultants" groups at the Collection level- as each of my projects will have a "Consultants" group with different membership and I would need to create the groups as "My Project Consultants", "My Other Project Consultants", Etc.  It also seems intuitive to create the groups at the project level as they are a project scope group.

It seems counter to logic that Collection-level groups are required to give Project-level rights.

So, My question is, do I really need to create my groups at the Collection level and give them "*view instance-level information*" or is there a way to assign the Project-level group appropriately without creating it as an Instance-level group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also a [**sever level**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/permissions#nbspnbspnbspserver-level-tfs)  **View instance-level information** permission.

First, please double check if you are lacking sever level or collection level View instance-level information permission.

The permission in TFS could be inherited, you should make sure `project\Consultants` in the sever level group or collection level group which has View instance-level information permission.

The project group Consultants could also inherite the corresponding permission. For example,  **Project Collection Valid Users** which contains all users and groups that have been added anywhere within the collection. You should check if this group lacking of  corresponding permission.

Moreover, you should also check the [access level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/change-access-levels)  for the users in `project\Consultants` group. People with Stakeholder  access level also have limitation features through the web portal.

Comment: This confused me more.  

adding project\Consultants to the collection level group results in :
_TF400031: You cannot add the project group Consultants to the global group AVIP._  
(AVIP is a group I created at the Collection level with _View instance-level permissions_ set to allow.

Then at the **Team Foundation Valid Users** level using the Admin Console it will not let me add any groups to that group... which I find very strange.  I also can't add users to the _project\Project Collection Valid Users_ the +Add is greyed out.

Comment: I think I figured out the issue. See my answer.

Comment: @Hal Sorry, haven't noticed this, you have already add the group. **Project Collection Valid Users**  Contains all users and groups that have been added anywhere within the collection. You cannot modify the membership of this group. That's why +Add is grayed out. Then you should check all your collection level group  lacking of corresponding view instance-level information permission. Have update my reply.

Answer (score 1):

[collection]\Project Collection Valid Users did not have the *View instance-level information* set to **Allow**. (I thought it was by default?)  Once I changed that, it resolved the issue.